# failed to get i915 symbols, graphics turbo disabled error on boot

Tags: boot, graphics, intel

Whenever I boot my laptop, I see this message and it makes the boot process very slow as my screen stays black for a long time before this message appears.
It shows just for a split second but today It got worst when my system couldn't boot and stuck on this error, I did several reboots but still couldn't pass this boot **error message**, then after sometime it fixed itself and now I can use my system as normal.

I didn't pay much attention to the error when It was there for just a split second and making my boot process slow, but now that it has stopped me from booting into my system, I would like to know why this error occurring.

**Error--**

> ...failed to get i915 symbols,
>   graphics turbo disabled....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug - see link [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/651104)

Answer (score 0):

Posting here the workaround suggested in the launchpad discussion:

add `intel_ips` to the blacklist:

```
echo "blacklist intel_ips" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

add `i915` and `intel_ips` to /etc/modules:

```
echo -e "i915\nintel_ips" >> /etc/modules
```

Comment: Workaround has caused errors too as detailed in the Launchpad discussion - [drm:i915_init] *ERROR* drm/i915 can't work without intel_agp module!                                                FWIW I have not had the issue when running Natty Alpha 2 on a live usb.